# How to install springs on werner loft/attic ladders?

Tags: attic, ladder, stretching-spring

I've just purchased the this [loft/attic ladder](http://www.toolstation.com/shop/Ladders+%26+Storage/d110/Loft+Ladders/sd3303/Werner+Timber+Complete+Loft+Ladder/p37662).

[image]

The installation instructions show that the springs must be installed while the ladder is closed (less tension in springs). Problem is even when closed its proving impossible to pull the springs by hand to link the two hooks (on either end) to the mounting brackets.

Can anyone think of a way to somehow mechanically extend the spring to allow it to be installed?

Comment: Can you post a picture of where the spring needs to be installed?

Comment: I haven't argued with that unit, but sometimes the answer is either leverage, or running a metal tool through the hook so you can hold it with one hand on each side and put your back/weight into it... Have you checked for installation videos? Have you checked the company website to see if they have a standard answer for this FAQ?

Comment: @bib  see the link in the question for picture. Springs can be seen along the sides. They have two rods either end that hook onto the spring and then theses rods hook onto brackets.

Comment: We need to see how the spring lines up with the attachment points when it is folded as directed.

Comment: To do it mechanically A small cable come-a-long would barely know it was pulling with those springs. It may take a little rigging to find/ make an anchor point like adding an large eye bolt to attach to on one of the rafters that could be removed when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the Werner Ladder Co. FAQ for wood folding attic ladders:

> For reattaching the springs on your model ladder you will need two people. One person will need to go into the attic and have the door closed. Once they are in overhead space and the person below is holding the ladder closed the springs will be able to carefully be removed. Please contact our customer care department at 888-523-3370 Monday through Friday 8 AM till 5 PM EST if you have any questions, or need any additional information

So... it seems to me that @keshlam's comment is correct, you need to use brute force. Get **two** people in the attic to help stretch the springs if you need to, while the door is held closed from below by a person standing out of the swing radius of the door and propping it up with a 2 x 4.

Or, using the above prescribed procedure for holding the door closed, have the person in the attic attach a "come-along" to the end loop of the spring and a sturdy anchor point. The spring could be easily stretched in this manner. Or fashion a block & tackle using some rope and a couple pulleys; it should be fairly easy to rig up a mechanical advantage for this.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Gaz_Edge:  I believe Jimmy Fix-it described how to stretch a spring with any of several tools, even providing hints how to do it in place.  Can you give an example of what you would like an answer to say?

Answer (score 2):

I've had to replace both springs and was able to do it quickly by following this procedure:

- Build and complete ladder on a flat floor
- The springs make a strong loop, so I used a very strong cable tie
- With a strong metal bar (.5 meter long, I used a 15mm wall drill) sit on the floor at the top end of the frame
- Put the loop around the spring hook, put the bar through the loop, then put your foot on the corner of the frame
- With both hands on the bar, pull the spring into place
- When it's hooked correctly just cut the loop/cable tie

Doing it like this was very easy, I think this would work for spring install as well as replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Paul! I submitted an edit that reformats your answer for readability, so future readers can follow your process more easily. While you're here, feel free to ask questions, answer questions to share your expertise, and also take the [tour] to get a better feel for how questions and answers work.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the springs. I first pulled the ladder down.  The metal lever system was attached to the wood ladder with a bolt. I climbed up the ladder part way, and  removed the bolt. This allowed the lever system to be pushed up so installation of the new spring was very easy. After installation of the new spring, I pulled the lever system down and reattached the bolt. Then I did the other side. Trying to replace the springs in the attic with the attic ladder closed is really not possible for a mortal man.